# What is wrong about this AWS cron ScheduleExpression?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, serverless-framework

Trying to run the schedule every monday at 8:15, I tried the following expression:

```
cron(15 8 * * MON *)
```

I thought this means:

- Minutes: 15
- Hour: 8
- Day-of-month: Every `*`
- Month: Every `*`
- Day-of-week: Monday only
- Year: Every

Documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the same [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html), your mistake is related with this restriction:

> #### Limits
>
> - You can't specify the Day-of-month and Day-of-week fields in the same
>     Cron expression. If you specify a value in one of the fields, you must
>     use a ? (question mark) in the other.

So, fix it using:

```
cron(15 8 ? * MON *)
```